# Azure DevOps set MultiLine Row parameter

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to set the `multiLine` row parameter in the `task.json` file for a custom task?

```
{
    "name":  "Include",
    "type":  "multiLine",
    "label":  "Include",
    "defaultValue":  "@(\"*.sln\")",
    "required":  false,
    "helpMarkDown":  "example help"
}
```

I recocnize, that the only difference between a `multiLine` textbox and `inline` textbox (PowerShell Task) is the amount of rows:

[image]

The default amount of rows of a `multiLine` textbox is **2**.

So it would be create to define the amount a rows in a `multiLine` control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to set the multiLine row parameter in the task.json
>   file for a custom task?

It's possible. `Use .net core task` have a textbox `Path to projects`:

[image]

Corresponding html see here:

[image]

Which is default rows of `MultiLine` type.

So I compared the source of Use .net core task and PS task [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks) and found:

```
       {
            "name": "projects",
            "type": "multiLine",
            "label": "Path to project(s)",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "visibleRule": "command = build || command = restore || command = run || command = test || command = custom || publishWebProjects = false",
            "required": false,
            "helpMarkDown": "The path to the csproj file(s) to use. You can use wildcards (e.g. **/*.csproj for all .csproj files in all subfolders)."
        }
```

and this:

```
        {
            "name": "script",
            "type": "multiLine",
            "label": "Script",
            "visibleRule": "targetType = inline",
            "required": true,
            "defaultValue": "# Write your PowerShell commands here.\n\nWrite-Host \"Hello World\"\n",
            "properties": {
                "resizable": "true",
                "rows": "10",
                "maxLength": "20000"
            },
            "helpMarkDown": ""
        }
```

The first script comes from dotnet task and second one comes from PS task. They both use `MultiLine` type.

According to the difference between these two scripts I think you can get what you want by setting the `rows` element in `properties` element. Something like this:

```
    "properties": {
        ...,
        "rows": "xxx",
        ...
    }
```

Hope it helps and if I misunderstand anything, feel free to correct me :)

Comment: Glad to know it helps :)